# Align first flex item to flex end

Tags: html, css, flexbox

**I can't touch the HTML file and the non-grey items should not change it's position**

I'm trying to have the `.grey` item be at the bottom of the other 4 items. I know there is another question very similar to this one but they are working with columns and I'm not so none of the answers there helped me.

```css
.red {
  background-color: #900;
}

.green {
  background-color: #090;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #00F;
}

.purple {
  background-color: #63C;
}

.grey {
  background-color: #666;
}

.container {
  background-color: #FFF;
  width: 50%;
  height: 70%;
  min-height: 400px;
  margin: auto;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
  width: 45%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-right: 2%;
  margin-top: 0;
}

.item:last-child {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item red"></div>
  <div class="item green"></div>
  <div class="item blue"></div>
  <div class="item purple"></div>
  <div class="item grey"></div>
</div>
```

I need the grey rectangle to be on the bottom

[image: I need the grey rectangle to be on the bottom]

Comment: Please post how the screenshot for how final layout should look like.

Comment: Why do you have `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;` ?

Comment: I can't modify the order of the divs in the HTML, and if i don't use `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse`, the colors would be in a different order.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add `order` to the item. It will align wherever you want.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="item red"></div>
    <div class="item green"></div>
    <div class="item blue"></div>
    <div class="item purple"></div>
    <div class="item grey"></div>
</div>
```

```
.red { background-color: #900; }
.green { background-color: #090; }
.blue { background-color: #00F; }
.purple { background-color: #63C; }
.grey { background-color: #666; }

.container {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 50%;
    height: 70%;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin: auto; 
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
    width: 45%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.item:last-child{
    width: 100%;
    order: -1; // It will make this item as first. Since it is reversed, this will be the last.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can easily do it with add an order to  `.grey` class

```
 .grey{
    order: -1;
    width: 100%; 
}
```

because it's justify-content is wrap-reverse ,
in the case you use wrap , you can add `order: 1;` or higher.

Answer (score 1):

If You want to have div class `.item grey` on the bottom, In this specific case, You have to change `flex-wrap: wrap-reverse` to `flex-wrap: wrap` that's it ;-) Best regards !

```css
.red { background-color: #900; }
.green { background-color: #090; }
.blue { background-color: #00F; }
.purple { background-color: #63C; }
.grey { background-color: #666; }

.container {
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 50%;
    height: 70%;
    min-height: 400px;
    margin: auto; 
    border: 2px solid black;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.item {
    width: 45%;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
    margin-top: 0;
}

.item:last-child{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item red"></div>
    <div class="item green"></div>
    <div class="item blue"></div>
    <div class="item purple"></div>
    <div class="item grey"></div>
</div>
```